# Bad word table for random alpha string?

Tags: algorithm, identifier

I'm writing an algorithm to generate a random 6-character string (e.g. customer code XDEJQW).  I want to ensure no and or offensive words or strings within.  I guess I have no choice but to have a database table of those bad words, right?  Just seems icky that I'll have to have an add/edit page for someone to go to that has some pretty awful words in it.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you use an Enum?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a table, you can either use a string array or an enum for this purpose. The advantage is that you do not have to send a request to get the records of the bad word table. It is better for performance. Basically you can randomize the 6-character value until the result does not contain bad words.

Comment: That won't work if the list is to be dynamic.  There's always going to be a new one that someone deems offensive.

Comment: And what stops you from adding the new value into your array/enum?

Answer (score 0):

depending on the purpose of the value, you can change the random process to make sure that no valid words are generate.. so if no valid words are generated.. offensive strings wont ether.. for example..

- use only consonants
- use only vowels
- use 3 consecutive consonants and 3 consecutive vowels
- etc..

the point is, normally, words of languages are made of syllables, a syllables to be pronounceable need to have a vowel.. usually paired with one or two (maybe more) consonants, before, after or around, that act as a "modifier"  of the sound `bi,ca,do`,`et,if,or` or `get,for` etc.. if you can avoid these "patterns"
the probability of generating a word is low..

on the other and if you want to generate pronounceable passwords you do exactly the opposite alternating between consonants and vowels to produce syllables, ex: `cidofe`, but in that case you do have to validate against a list of "bad words"

but in ether case remember if you are going to validate.. don't just validate against a full word also try to filter out partial words, misspells or abbreviation to avoid things like `SUKMYDIK`